# MongoDB over Traditional File Based System

Tags: mongodb, filesystems

Presently we have 2 systems. System1 places the JSON/XML structures in folder1. System2 runs batch job that reads the JSON/XML from folder1 and process it. If the JSON parsing is successful, the batchjob places the JSON/XML in another folder.

I want to replace this mechanism and use MongoDB. My idea: system 1 places JSON in MongoDB and Sytem2 reads from MongoDB and updates the JSON if successful.

Let me know if this is a good idea. Also can someone give me some solid advantages which i can use to convince my team to use MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores data as BSON which is like JSON. If you use MongoDB, you don't need to store data as XML and it reduces the data volume because of XML syntax complexity. Also you can store denormalized data in MongoDB and you can handle inconsistent situations. MongoDB serves more programmable data format, so you can do everything data without any constraints. If you don't need consistent data, you can use MongoDB.